# How to use multiple variable in bash

Tags: bash, text-processing

I have a file (`user.txt`) with the below content with 90+ users

- example file content

  ```
  user: Ronaldo
  id:7
  endpoint:manutd.com
  user: Messi
  id:30
  endpoint:psg.com
  user: Neymar
  id:10
  endpoint:psg.com
  ```
- desired output:

  ```
  Ronaldo is in manutd.com and wears no 7
  Messi is in psg.com and wears no 30
  .
  .
  ```

  and so on for all the users

How can I print this way via a Bash script?

Comment: Does it have to be a bash script? Text-processing via shell loops is [discouraged](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/169716/why-is-using-a-shell-loop-to-process-text-considered-bad-practice), as more efficient solutions exist.

Comment: @AdminBee You could use `awk` in a `bash` script...

Comment: @Kusalananda Yes, that is of course true.

Comment: upper and lowercase is not important here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this `awk`

```
awk -F: '/user/ {name=$2 " is in "; next} /id/{id="no "$2;next} /endpoint/ {team=$2 " and wears "} {print name, team, id }' $inputfile
```

**Output**

```
 Ronaldo is in  manutd.com and wears  no 7
 Messi is in  psg.com and wears  no 30
 Neymar is in  psg.com and wears  no 10
```

I am assuming your expected output with capitalization is wrong, but if not, please  point this out.

Answer (score 1):

With `sed`:

```
$ sed -n 'N;N;s/^user: *\(.*\)\nid: *\(.*\)\nendpoint: *\(.*\)/\1 is in \3 and wears no \2/p' file
Ronaldo is in manutd.com and wears no 7
Messi is in psg.com and wears no 30
Neymar is in psg.com and wears no 10
```

Answer (score 1):

bash:

```bsh
declare -A record
while IFS=":$IFS" read -r key value; do
    record[$key]=$value
    if [[ -v 'record[user]' && -v 'record[id]' && -v 'record[endpoint]' ]]; then
        printf '%s is in %s and wears no %s\n' "${record[user]}" "${record[endpoint]}" "${record[id]}"
        record=()
    fi
done < file.content
```